# Supporting Multiple devices in android

Tags: android-screen-support

I am new to android development. I want my application to run on multiple resolution. I went through documentation, some stackoverflow post's. I end up with creating multiple layout's. Which I have done in my project.
Here is my layout structure:

- layout-normal-mdpi
- layout-normal-hdpi
- layout-normal-xhdpi
- layout-large-mdpi
- layout-large-hdpi
- layout-large-xhdpi

and my drawable folder structure is

- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi

I added

```
 <supports-screens 
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true" 
              android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

in my manifest file. 
It looks good on mdpi devices(not tested on all) Tested on Htc-epxlorer Sony-experia tipo.
I tested it on Sony xperia arc s hdpi device and htc one v it looks good.
but when it comes to Samasung galaxy Note and Note 2.Its totally messed up!.
I end up with solution for creating layout folder like layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800. Which works but i feel not a good practice.
I have images of resolution (Port mode)

- for mdpi : 480X320
- for hdpi : 800X480
- for xhdpi: 1280X800

Even with Galaxy nexsus 4.65in(720p). It gives different feel. Basically what I want to know is what should be the image resolutions for different densities? and what should be layout folder structure for different devices?.Cause it gives different look on different inch devices like I said on 4in nexsus and 4.6in nexsus it looks different when I am adding Images. Even tablets are of resolutions 1280X800.
Why things go wrong even with the same resolution but just screen size change?.
Note: I have used RelativeLayout as layout and no hardcoded pixel values everything is in dp.
Any help will be appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance.